# how to redirect Parked domain in website files via nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

so I'm using ubuntu, and my files are at /home/ubuntu/this_file

whenever I am parking a domain under the IP address of the server, nginx welcome message appears. so how to redirect the this_file(my web files) via nginx?

I am using SSH for commands.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.
Almost every line is commented, it's easy to set up.

Comment: Hello sir, can you elaborate more of the information? I'm apologize for I don't know what you're talking since I am new to this. have a great day.